# MySQL InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT fails after restoring dump

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, innodb

I have database with InnoDB tables in a production server and development. Several tables have auto_increment columns and there are few Foreign Keys also included.

Problem is that after taking a dump (schema and data) from production to development server, suddenly NO new insert from PHP increases any auto_increment key and they result having ai_key 0
in the table. I thought this should even not be possible without touching sql_mode setting on server. After this 0-key, all procedures just updates the 0-key row on database.

Insert goes like this (just for example):

```
IF vCol = 0 AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM aTable WHERE `aId` = vId) = 0     
THEN
    INSERT INTO aTable (
        `aId`,
        `bRandomCol`
    )
    VALUES
    (
        vCol,
        vRandomCol
    )
```

Using mysqli and prepared statements in PHP.

Calling prosedure outside PHP also fails. Making pure insert clause including auto_increment field into it and giving value 0 for it, that succeeds.

Inspecting table with SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM X LIKE 'Y' results the correct key  in order.

I can repair the problem with ALTER TABLE X AUTO_INCREMENT = Z.

Have anyone seen problem like this before or know why this happens or is there any workaround?

Comment: Is `aId` your autoincrement column?  If so, why are you specifying a value for this in the insert?  Also look at your logic.  You are running that insert on the condition that vCol = 0 and then you insert the value of vCol into aId.  This makes no logical sense.

Comment: Im testing in the procedure that if its 0, is a NEW record, otherwise I do update what is arter that IF clause. 0 is easy id-basevalue for objects that are new. Mysql Reference manual says: "No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly assign 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers. If the column is declared NOT NULL, it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers. "

Comment: Yes, but that behavior for InnoDB changes depending on what version you are running. Specifically, this behavior only exists for InnoDB in Mysql 5.6+. Do you have different MySQL versions in prod and dev environments? I would bet if you did a more typical approach and did not specify autoincrement values upon insert, that this problem would go away.

Comment: mysql server version is 5.5.41 in both dev and prod. Your suggestion is one I have thought also. Its just...this logic has worked on MyISAM tables always ;). First time now that i bumped into a problem like this... Thanks Mike for the info for now will try it!

Comment: Yes MyISAM has supported that sort of behavior going back always (not sure exactly how far back, as it has always been any any version of MySQL I have used).